# How to increase width and height of an iframe which is created tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and TinyMCE and I have added an iframe to this editor and make a new post with it.

Then at the Blade, I tried retrieving data like this:

```
<!-- News Content -->
<div class="text-justify mt-3">
   {!! $new->nws_description !!}
</div>
```

And it correctly shows the content but the only problem is that the iframe is small size.

So I need to increase the width and height of the iframe but don't know how to do that!

Here is the contents of `$new->nws_description` which is stored at the DB:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: justify;"><code></code></p>
<div class="h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame" style="text-align: center;"><iframe title="iframe-title" src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: justify;"><code></code></p>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
<div id="4591871988"></div>
<div id="92356425254"></div>
```

So how to increase the iframe size automatically?  So it would be like this:

`<iframe width="100%" height="100%" ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with style, just target the element

```
<style>
.h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame iframe{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
 }
</style>
```